# Which functions of groupby, transpose, append or pivot to use in Pandas? And how to use them?

Tags: python, pandas, pivot, pandas-groupby

I have a pandas dataframe like the following:

```
df_starting_point = pd.DataFrame(
                      [{'robot_id': 130, 'work_id': 1, 'grade': '1', 'time' : 1},
                       {'robot_id': 141, 'work_id': 2, 'grade': '3', 'time' : 1},
                       {'robot_id': 141, 'work_id': 60, 'grade': '4', 'time' : 1},
                       {'robot_id': 17013, 'work_id': 1, 'grade': '1', 'time' : 1},
                       {'robot_id': 17013, 'work_id': 1478, 'grade': '5', 'time' : 1},
                       {'robot_id': 17013, 'work_id': 1478, 'grade': '4', 'time' : 2},
                       {'robot_id': 17013, 'work_id': 230, 'grade': '2', 'time' : 1},
                       {'robot_id': 130, 'work_id': 123, 'grade': '1', 'time' : 1},
                       {'robot_id': 17013, 'work_id': 2, 'grade': '2', 'time' : 1}
                      ])
```

I want to create a pandas dataframe out of it, like the following:

```
df_end_point = pd.DataFrame(
                  [{'robot_id': 130, '1': 1, '2': np.nan, '60': np.nan, '123': 1, '230': np.nan, '1478': np.nan},
                   {'robot_id': 141, '1': np.nan, '2': 3, '60': 4, '123': np.nan, '230': np.nan, '1478': np.nan},
                   {'robot_id': 17013, '1': 1, '2': 2 , '60': np.nan, '123': np.nan, '230': 2, '1478': 4},
                  ])
```

In **df_starting_point**

- every **robot_id** has muliple entries for different **work_id**.
- Every completed **work_id** is graded.
- It is possible for a **robot_id** to complete **work_id** muliple times. So one **robot_id**   could have multiple **grade** for the same **work_id**.

For **df_end_point** I would like:

- 1 row for every unique **robot_id**
- 1 column for every occurring **work_id**, where **work_id** is the lable
- As entry the respective **grade**. If there are muliple grade, the one with the highest number in **time** should be entried.

I tried a couple of pandas function already, but I'm struggeling with getting the wanted result and I'm not sure if my approach is reasonable. I also found some similar questions here, but I can't manage to apply them to my problem.

How do I do this in Pandas? Is there an elegant way of doing that?
Could you be so kind and try to explain what you are doing?

Thank you. Any help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea is to filter for only rows where time is maximum, after grouping, then converting to integers, so that the null cells can be filled up after another grouping by sum.

```
(
    df_starting_point.set_index(["robot_id", "work_id"], append=True)
    .assign(temp=lambda x: x.groupby(["robot_id", "work_id"]).time.transform("max"))
    .query("time==temp")
    .drop(["time", "temp"], axis=1)
    .astype(int)
    .unstack()
    .groupby("robot_id")
    .sum(min_count = 1)
)


                                  grade
work_id  1     2    60    123   230 1478
robot_id                        
130     1.0   NaN   NaN   1.0   NaN   NaN
141     NaN   3.0   4.0   NaN   NaN   NaN
17013   1.0   2.0   NaN   NaN   2.0   4.0
```

Comment: First of all thanks, it seem to work. Is there are a way to do that with pivot? It seems to me, this function is made for use cases like mine.

Comment: ``pivot`` works on single index; besides, with pivot you wont be able to filter for rows where ``time is ``max``